# Появление блока при наведении на область

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Необходимо реализовать следующее: при наведении на область картинки, должен появляться `div` с текстом. За основу решил взять принцип работы `image map`, но не получается реализовать появление блока при наведении.
Необязательно использовать `image map`, можно и любым другим способом.

```css
.targetPhoto img {
  width: 100%;
}

.text_block {
  border: 1px solid #b0b0ce;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  background: #b0b0ce;
  color: #000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 7px #000;
  width: 120px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.text_block::after,
.text_block::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #b0b0ce;
  left: 20px;
  bottom: 35px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 7px #000;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.text_block::before {
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://cs.pikabu.ru/post_img/2013/05/31/6/1369989185_1245917493.jpg" usemap="#image-map">
<map name="image-map">
  <area target="_blank" alt="1" title="1" href="profile.html" coords="73,188,70" shape="circle">
  <area target="_blank" alt="2" title="2" href="profile.html" coords="241,112,64" shape="circle">
</map>
<div class="text_block">
  котейка
</div>
```

Comment: Хорошо, если Вам нужен только текст, почему просто не прописать необходимый текст в title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ну как вариант, всегда есть js

на css тоже можно - зависит от ситуации. Примерно так:

```css
.targetPhoto img {
  width: 100%;
}

.text_block {
  border: 1px solid #b0b0ce;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  background: #b0b0ce;
  color: #000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 7px #000;
  width: 120px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  display: none;
}

#text_block_1:hover ~ .text_block_1 {
  display: block;
}
#text_block_2:hover ~ .text_block_2 {
  display: block;
}

.text_block::after,
.text_block::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #b0b0ce;
  left: 20px;
  bottom: 35px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 7px #000;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.text_block::before {
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://cs.pikabu.ru/post_img/2013/05/31/6/1369989185_1245917493.jpg" usemap="#image-map">
<map name="image-map">
  <area id="text_block_1" target="_blank" alt="1" title="1" href="profile.html" coords="73,188,70" shape="circle">
  <area id="text_block_2" target="_blank" alt="2" title="2" href="profile.html" coords="241,112,64" shape="circle">
  
  <div class="text_block text_block_1">
    котейка
  </div>
  <div class="text_block text_block_2">
    котейка 2
  </div>
</map>
```

Answer (score 0):

Идея, в общем то та же, что у Юрия. Так, попилил немножко)))

```css
.targetPhoto img {
  width: 100%;
}
img {
 position: relative;
}
.text_block {
  border: 1px solid #b0b0ce;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #b0b0ce;
  color: #000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 7px #000;
  width: 120px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  opacity: 0;
}
.text_block::after,
.text_block::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #b0b0ce;
  left: 20px;
  bottom: 35px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 7px #000;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  opacity: 0;
}
area[alt='1']:hover + div {
 opacity: 1;
 transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
 left: 80px;
 top: 270px;
}
area[alt='2']:hover + div {
 opacity: 1;
 transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
 left: 300px;
 top: 270px;
}
area:hover + .text_block::before {
 box-shadow: none;
 z-index: 1;
 opacity: 1;
 transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://cs.pikabu.ru/post_img/2013/05/31/6/1369989185_1245917493.jpg" usemap="#image-map">
<map name="image-map">
  <area target="_blank" alt="1" title="текст1" href="profile.html" coords="73,188,70" shape="circle">
  <div class="text_block">Котейка1</div>
  <area target="_blank" alt="2" title="текст2" href="profile.html" coords="350,188,64" shape="circle">
  <div class="text_block">Котейка2</div>
</map>
```